# I cannot solve "Missing Controller Error"

Tags: php, cakephp

I should have made the correct name controller,
but Missing Controller Error will not disappear.

I am doing cakePHP tutorial from https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/articles-controller.html

It is in /kaede/code/cake/cms/src/Controller

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;

class ArticlesController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
        $articles = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Articles->find());
        $this->set(compact('articles'));
    }
    public function edit() {
        $article = $this->Articles->findBySlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
        }
        $this->set('article', $article);
    }
}
```

Missing Controller
ArticleController could not be found.
Create the class ArticleController below in file: src/Controller/ArticleController.php

Comment: It was insame, I should write single ArticleController extends....

Comment: Does Article and Articles spelling matter?

Comment: yeah, I am so sorry.....

Answer (score 0):

Full source code can be found here for that tutorial.
https://github.com/cakephp/cms-tutorial/blob/master/src/Controller/ArticlesController.php

Double check the spelling of Article and Articles, it could be the case.

```
public function edit($slug)
    {
        $article = $this->Articles
            ->findBySlug($slug)
            ->contain('Tags') // load associated Tags
            ->firstOrFail();
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->getData(), [
                // Added: Disable modification of user_id.
                'accessibleFields' => ['user_id' => false]
            ]);
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
        }
        // Get a list of tags.
        $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list');
        // Set article & tags to the view context
        $this->set('tags', $tags);
        $this->set('article', $article);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

class name was singler.

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {
```

Comment: Did you mean singular? Also, the code snippet you show is identical to that in your question. Exactly how does this solve your problem?